# How to import the ruby flickr gem "Flickraw" into eclipse?

Tags: ruby, eclipse, flickr

I'm totally new to Ruby but I'd like to use it for a small application I've in mind.

But I'm struggeling at the beginning: How can I use the library "flickraw" in order to access the flickr api within eclipse?

I've managed to update ruby to 1.9.3 but in eclipse I found only an older interpreter (1.8).

- Could someone please tell me how I can show eclipse where ruby 1.9.3 is installed?

Beside of that, how can I use this flickraw library in eclipse? I only know how to import jar's for a  java project but not how to do it for a ruby project :(

- Could someone please tell me how I can import a external ruby library into eclipse?

Machine: Mac OS X Mountain Lion,
IDE: Eclipse Juno,
flickraw library: http://hanklords.github.com/flickraw/

many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You've probably already answered your question (being 6 months ago), but I answer this to help future generations of Eclipse Rubyists who come upon your question.

I assume you're using Eclipse RDT (Ruby Development Tools). I'm using Eclipse Juno (4.2.1) on Windows, but the menu items should be the same on any OS for similar versions of Eclipse.

To change or set your Eclipse Ruby interpreter:

1. Go to "Windows" > "Preferences"
2. Click the "Ruby" entry on the left pane of the "Preferences" window
3. Click the "Interpreter" subentry (also on the left pane)
4. Click the "Add" button
5. Click "Browse" by the Interpreter Executable text box
6. Now find your Ruby executable - I used RailsInstaller on Win7, so mine is in C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin
7. If you found a good executable, Eclipse should figure out the rest of the interpreter information itself

To import Ruby libraries into an Eclipse project: I'm not sure per se. This is what led me to your post. I thought I needed to import all my gems by hand. But when I used the gem installer ("./gem install targetgem") and restarted Eclipse, Eclipse was magically aware of the gems. (I'm not sure what dark magic allowed Eclipse to do that.)

Hope this helps future Rubyites.